# Connect VPN with same Private Network

Tags: vpn, nat, subnet

i have my Private Network on my Apartment that is 192.168.1.x/24 and in the Office we have Private Network 192.168.1.x/16. Is it possible to connect them through VPN, but i will not change my private Subnet. I think that i need to Configure with NAT Policies. But, i can not find a solution. Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Sadly, home networking is off topic here. You can get more information on [su].

Comment: Also, you would need to work with the office network administrators to configure the office network, but questions about networks you do not directly control are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Renumber.

You'd need source and destination NAT which will be a major pain. You'd need to fiddle with DNS as well to provide pre-NAT IP addresses. Save yourself the hassle and renumber one side.

As a compromise, you could try adding secondary IP addresses to your office devices (only statically, no DHCP) - that way you can keep the office addresses and use the secondary addresses from remote.